# how to Shim Enumerable Cast In Unit Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I used in EF Expression Like this,

```
query
    .Select(item => new
    {
        DoubleValue =
            new List<string>() { item.AdmissionTicketCode }
                .Cast<double>()
                .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```

but, run at Unit Test it thorw an error "Specified Cast Is Not Valid".

how do I deal this problem

### [System.Linq.Enumerable ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuXkd.png)

I tried to add System.Linq.Fakes、and wanted use ShimEnumerable to resolve it, but it does not exist in System.Linq.Fakes.

Comment: You can't `(double)"string"`, so why would you expect Linq to do that with each element of an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: `.Cast<double>()` is a NOP on a double and will throw on any other type. Also, keep in mind, that a cast is not a conversion. If `item.AdmissionTicketCode` is a `string` then you need to parse it, not cast it.

Comment: just an example, i used in 'where expression' to convert to a number when it is a number string  for order at Expression bfore tolist

Answer (score 0):

`.Cast<double>()` is a NOP on a double and will throw on any other type. Also, keep in mind, that a cast is not a conversion. If `item.AdmissionTicketCode` is a string then you need to parse it, not cast it.

So let's break down what you might need to do.

Your current code is equivalent to:

```
query
    .Select(item => new
    {
        DoubleValue = (double)item.AdmissionTicketCode
    })
    .ToList();
```

Assuming that `item.AdmissionTicketCode` is a `string` then the compiler lets us know it's a bad cast right now.

So it should be like this:

```
query
    .Select(item => new
    {
        DoubleValue = double.Parse(item.AdmissionTicketCode)
    })
    .ToList();
```

It's a bit pointless having a single property in an anonymous type, so you could go one step further:

```
query
    .Select(item => double.Parse(item.AdmissionTicketCode))
    .ToList();
```

---

If EF doesn't support `double.Parse` then do this:

```
query
    .Select(item => item.AdmissionTicketCode)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => double.Parse(x))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: throw "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"
so I used Cast to avoid this error

Comment: @BluckHuang - Then do the conversion after the `.ToList()`.

Comment: thanks fo answer this question again, but in our requirement  i used in 'Order expression' to convert to a number when it is a number string, then order at Expression bfore tolist.
``ThenBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.AdmissionTicketCode) == 1 ? new List<string>() { item.AdmissionTicketCode }.Cast<double>().FirstOrDefault() : double.MaxValue)``

Comment: If `AdmissionTicketCode` is a number, then store it as a number. Or are you trying to perform some kind of "natural" sorting?

Comment: thanks for reply, I used it by a complicated way，and not a simple order。in order to save programing time, I will shim the function where used the ``Cast``, and in shimed i will use memory type convertion.
thanks reapply again.